# TokenMismatchException (put запрос). Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

у меня выскакивает ошибка:  **TokenMismatchException**
Я на этот url отправляю put запрос `admin_panel/article/12/edit` в laravel.
В ручную записал путь:`Route::put("/article/{id?}/edit","Action\ArticleController@update");`

Как мне это записать в **Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken**
Пробовал что-то наподобии такого `admin_panel/article/{id?}/edit`- не катит

P.S В blade записать не вариант, ибо все что у меня в blade перенес во vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` поддерживает вайлдкарды, просто пропишите в `except`:

```
/admin_panel/article/*
```

Теперь он не будет проверять ваш url и все что попадут под шаблон.

P.S. Vue использует `axios` на сколько я помню, можно в него передавать CSRF чтобы все запросы шли с этим параметром.

Comment: Там это вообще в шаблоне по умолчанию есть ```let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}```

Comment: /admin_panel/article/* - не знал про такой подход, спасибо.
Безопасно ведь так делать?

Comment: @Andrey смотря с какой стороны смотреть, вообще отключение CSRF не безопасно, но это же админка, по идее только админ будет пользоваться этим роутом.